# Updating a big table in oracle without drooping the base table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to update a table in sql query. My table contains half a million records and it is taking around 10 minutes of time. It is my dev environment.

When i will go for UAT or prod, the table there will contain a lot more data than the dev environment. updating the whole table and then putting a commit will consume a lot of memory. Can someone suggest me a good way of updating a table in batches.

I have gone through net and the most common solution i found is creating a new table by "create new_table as select (update ) from old_table." But in my case i can not use this as in my prod environment i can not drop  and create table.

Thanks
Ankit.

Comment: Update them in batches of 10000 in a loop while the row count updated > 0. Do commit inside loop, this will stop your rollback blowing out, and if you stop midway through it can pick up where it left off.

Comment: Hi Ab Bennett, i do not want to go into PL/SQL as i am trying to avoid context switches

Comment: What's the big deal with switching,  you are trying to find the right balance, just don't do it every row. Well to answer your question, if you can't use pl/swl, nor will use a new table, your only option is a single update. Make sure u have a big rollback segment . You will be disappointed if u run out of space. For the record, context switching is no big deal if you are not doing every row. 10 mill row table, update in chucks of 100k, that is 100 commits / switches

Comment: Maybe do in an anonymous block

Comment: @abbennett - Committing inside a loop introduces its own complications. You need to make sure the transaction is resumable in the face of failure. You need to avoid ORA-01555 errors.

Comment: When you say you cannot drop and create tables do you mean **you**, your user account, or do you mean nobody is allowed to execute DDL?

Comment: So what's the alternative. You have to commit sometime. whether in chunks of 10k or all at once

Comment: @APC , basically this approach  is not excepted by the upper management.

Comment: Is the table partitioned?

Comment: So can't commit inside loop, so only way you suggest is one monster update. 94% of the way through your rollback fills up, and starts rolling back,

Comment: do it in pl/sql : create a cursor and add some "dataset partitioning key"(use the MOD function to modulo it for example per 100 000) to separate it to smaller data sets, and update it along that "part_key" in a loop

Comment: "updating the whole table and then putting a commit will consume a lot of memory".  Not true at all.  It will require disk -- UNDO, specifically, but disk is cheap.  It is a common misconception that periodic commits are a good thing.  I advise you to reconsider your approach, size your UNDO sufficiently for your largest transaction (which may just be this one), and do it as a single update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTAS remains the fastest option. Bear in mind you don't need to drop the original table; you can just rename and retain it to keep your management happy.

Otherwise you have some options depending on your circumstances.

If:

- the concern is just about elapsed time; and
- you have the Enterprise Edition license; and
- Production has CPUs to spare

Then you could consider Parallel DML to solve the problem.

```
alter session enable parallel dml;

update /*+ parallel (your_table) */ your_table
set ..
```

If you have only Standard Edition but are on 11gR2 or higher you can use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE package to run a PL/SQL job in parallel. The caveats about CPU still apply.

Beyond that, you should look at the efficiency of the WHERE clause. An UPDATE is a scan too and can be tuned like any other query.

Splitting the update into batches will make the total elapsed time longer. Of course it will, you're doing more work. The main advantage of batching over a single update statement is that by committing chunks of records we don't lose work if the task falls over halfway through. This is only an advantage if there is a mechanism for distinguishing the updated records ( a status or date column which is updated by this task **and no  other**). If you don't have  a flag like that you run the risk of corrupting the table absolutely.

The simplest way of batching is a simple PL/SQL loop. Assuming you have a million rows to update:

```
begin
    for idx in 1..100 loop
         update your_table
         set whatever = whatever * 1.1
                    , status = 'touched'
         where status != 'touched'
          and rownum <= 10000;
          commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

Obviously you'll need some error handling, perhaps logging, etc. But resist the lure of `bulk collect`, `forall` etc unless your update rules are sufficiently complicated that they demand procedural logic.

Answer (score 0):

If "Create Table as Select" is not an option, then your best bet is to write a PL/SQL stored proc that takes advantage of `BULK COLLECT` and `FORALL` statements. This is a good starting point http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html